# `std::condition_var::notify_all` deadlocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have cpp code where one thread produces, pushing data into a queue and another consumes it before passing it to other libraries for processing.

```
std::mutex lock;
std::condition_variable new_data;
std::vector<uint8_t> pending_bytes;
bool data_done=false;

// producer
  void add_bytes(size_t byte_count, const void *data)
  {
    if (byte_count == 0)
        return;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
    uint8_t *typed_data = (uint8_t *)data;
    pending_bytes.insert(pending_bytes.end(), typed_data,
                               typed_data + byte_count);

    new_data.notify_all();
  }

  void finish()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);

    data_done = true;
    new_data.notify_all();
  }

// consumer
Result *process(void)
{
  data_processor = std::unique_ptr<Processor>(new Processor());

  bool done = false;
  while (!done)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(lock);
    new_data.wait(guard, [&]() {return data_done || pending_bytes.size() > 0;});

    size_t byte_count = pending_bytes.size();
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_copy;
    if (byte_count > 0)
    {
      data_copy = pending_bytes; // vector copies on assignment
      pending_bytes.clear();
    }

    done = data_done;
    guard.unlock();

    if (byte_count > 0)
    {
      data_processor->process(byte_count, data_copy.data());
    }
  }

  return data_processor->finish();
}
```

Where `Processor` is a rather involved class with a lot of multi-threaded processing, but as far as I can see it should be separated from the code above.

Now sometimes the code deadlocks, and I'm trying to figure out the race condition. My biggest clue is that the producer threads appears to be stuck under `notify_all()`. In GDB I get the following backtrace, showing that `notify_all` is waiting on something:

```
[Switching to thread 3 (Thread 0x7fffe8d4c700 (LWP 45177))]

#0  0x00007ffff6a4654d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff6a44240 in pthread_cond_broadcast@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff67e1b29 in std::condition_variable::notify_all() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000000001221177 in add_bytes (data=0x7fffe8d4ba70, byte_count=256,
    this=0x7fffc00dbb80) at Client/file.cpp:213
```

while also owning the lock

```
(gdb) p lock
$12 = {<std::__mutex_base> = {_M_mutex = {__data = {__lock = 1, __count = 0, __owner = 45177, __nusers = 1, __kind = 0,
        __spins = 0, __elision = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}},
```

with the other thread waiting in the condition variable wait

```
[Switching to thread 5 (Thread 0x7fffe7d4a700 (LWP 45180))]
#0  0x00007ffff6a43a35 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6a43a35 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff67e1aec in std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000000000121f9a6 in std::condition_variable::wait<[...]::{lambda()#1}>(std::
unique_lock<std::mutex>&, [...]::{lambda()#1}) (__p=..., __lock=...,
    this=0x7fffc00dbb28) at /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_mutex.h:104
```

There are two other threads running under the `Process` data part, which also hang on `pthread_cond_wait`, but as far as I'm aware they do not share any synchronization primities (and are just waiting for calls to `processor->add_data` or `processor->finish`)
Any ideas what `notify_all` is waiting for? or ways of finding the culprit?

Edit: I reproduced the code with a dummy processor here:
https://onlinegdb.com/lp36ewyRSP
But, pretty much as expected, this doesn't reproduce the issue, so I assume there is something more intricate going on. Possibly just different timings, but maybe some interaction between `condition_variable` and `OpenMP` (used by the real processor) could cause this?

Comment: try initializing global variable `data_done` to `false`.

Comment: @Harry sorry, everything is initialized in the codebase, just tried getting a snippet here quickly

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve]. The fact that you tried but then failed to reproduce the issue means you need to work on that part still.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt As much as I want to, the additional code running in this example is imported from dynamically linked libraries whose source code I can't access. Trying to reproduce it is either understanding the issue or shooting in the dark. I'd rather hope that someone knows what might cause this issue, which would make it reproducible..

Comment: That still means that your question is off-topic, I'm afraid, even though it's an interesting problem. Anyhow, here's one thing that struck me: "/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include/c++/9/bits/std_mutex.h". I don't know what that is, but in the end, you are using a libstdc++ from the system in combination with that, which may or may not be a good mix. Maybe, even if you can't post it here, creating a [mcve] still would help? Also, pay attention to the build env to avoid e.g. mixing different C++ ABIs.

Comment: It looks to me that if your consumer hits the new_data.wait(...) while there is no pending data that you will have a deadlock situation. Your producer will be stuck waiting for the consumer to unlock the mutex that it locked in the line before the new_data.wait(...)

Comment: Do you still get a deadlock if you remove `Processor`? Your synchronization mechanism does not require it

Comment: @Harry -- the global variable `data_done` gets initialized to `false` if it doesn't have an explicit initializer. All global variables of builtin types without initializers are initialized to 0.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I appreciate that clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that every piece of code that accesses this condition variable uses precisely the same instance of `std::mutex`?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. After doing a few experiments, I found that if the notify_all starts to work after the condition_variable destroying, the notify_all will deadlocks.

See the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::thread* t;
void test() {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_m;
    t = new std::thread([&](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout << "...before notify_all\n";
        cv.notify_all();
        std::cout << "...after notify_all\n";
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return true;});
    std::cout << "...finished waiting\n";
}

int main()
{
    test();
    t->join();
}
```

On linux:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Release:    6.3
Codename:   Final
```

uname info:

```
Linux xxx_name 3.10.0_3-0-0-34 #1 SMP Sun Apr 26 22:58:21 CST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Compile the code using gcc 8.2.0:

```
g++ --std=c++11 test.cpp -o test_cond -lpthread
```

The program will hang on after outputing "...before notify_all", and nerver reach "...after notify_all".

However, compile the code using gcc 12.1.0 the program will run successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you should unlock your mutex in the producer before the call to notify_all (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Comment: No, that's not required.

Comment: You definitely should not. That just makes performance worse.